# How to create a soap request using Python ElementTree, LXML or similar library

Tags: python, xml, soap, elementtree

I am trying to create XML SOAP request using data from excel sheet. Currentlly, I have used mako templates but it requires XML template. How do I create a request with namespace like below (this is just a small sample not the complete XML):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mes="http://www.orange.com/Webalc/Interfaces/ManageSupplierQuote/RequestForQuotation/v3/message">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mes:CalculateSupplierQuote>
         <!--1 to 500 repetitions:-->
         <SupplierQuote>
            <local_circuittype>Existing circuit</local_circuittype>
            <local_businessOpportunity>Access to Orange Business Services Network</local_businessOpportunity>
            <local_accessType>Upgrade/downgrade of full path diversity</local_accessType>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <local_configurationSite>single</local_configurationSite>
```

By using lxml library I am able to make some progress but then I am stuck. Below is the code that I have created.

```
from lxml import etree
import lxml.etree
import lxml.builder


Envelope = etree.Element("{http://www.w3.org/1999/soapenv}xmlns")
body = etree.SubElement(Envelope, "{http://www.w3.org/1999/soapenv}body")

print(etree.tostring(Envelope, pretty_print=True))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code and what it outputs.
Also the XML that you posted isn't valid, please post the full file.

Comment: Hi @PabloArias, I have edited my question. I did this code last week after that I started working on mako template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are constructing the Envelope element wrong.
The constructor of *etree.Element* receives the (fully qualified) name (a.k.a tag) of the xml element you want to create, which is in your case *Envelope*.

Change the first line to this:

```
envelope = etree.Element("{http://www.w3.org/1999/soapenv}Envelope")
```

Comment: I am getting the following output. How to replace the ns0 with soapenv?

`<ns0:envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <ns1:body xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/1999/soapenv"/>
</ns0:envelope>`

Comment: @PowellMittra: etree.register_namespace("soapenv", <url>)