# How to create SOAP envelope in Python?

Tags: python, xml, soap, lxml, suds

I am trying to create an XML file and send a SOAP request to an endpoint. How can I do it with Python. My final XML SOAP request should look like below (a small sample, not the complete xml) :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mes="http://www.orange.com/Webalc/Interfaces/ManageSupplierQuote/RequestForQuotation/v3/message">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mes:UpdateSupplierQuote>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <SupplierQuote>
            <Requester>
               <local_userName>anant4</local_userName>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <local_SalesID></local_SalesID>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <local_SourcingFTID></local_SourcingFTID>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <local_AnalystBuyer>Analyst</local_AnalystBuyer>
            </Requester>
            <!--1 to 100 repetitions:-->
            <QuoteItem>
               <quoteItemID>m19</quoteItemID>
               <simulation_id>10061191</simulation_id>
```

My starting XML file is:

```
<Header/>
   <Body>
      <CalculateSupplierQuote>
         <!--1 to 500 repetitions:-->
         <SupplierQuote>
            <local_circuittype>Existing circuit</local_circuittype>
            <local_businessOpportunity>Access to Orange Business Services Network</local_businessOpportunity>
            <local_accessType>Upgrade/downgrade of full path diversity</local_accessType>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <local_configurationSite>single</local_configurationSite>
            <currencyCode>USD</currencyCode>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <projectName>test</projectName>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <asynchronousPPUrl/>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <local_region/>
            <requester>
```

Is there a python library for this task or I need to use LXML or Elementree and create XML using namespace? Please help!

Comment: This looks very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/43494942/407651. What is the problem?

Comment: I use this library, it's quite satisfying: http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/